# Java/Javascript/JSON - Passing JSON string from Java into Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets

I'm passing a JSON string I create in Java as a parameter to a Javascript method called from my servlet. However, when I pass the JSON string, Firebug warns me about the string being passed:

Java code:

```
String jsonString = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Joe Smith\",\"data\":{\"email\":\"smith@gmail.com\",\"phone\":\"555-123-4567\",\"title\":\"CFO\",\"instanceControllerTagLibraryApi\":{\"developmentMode\":false}},\"children\":[],\"instanceControllerTagLibraryApi\":{\"developmentMode\":false}}";

pw.println("<body onload=\"init('"+jsonString+"');\">");
```

Javascript:

```
function init(text){
    alert(text);
}
```

I've tried quoting the string during the pass and removing the single quotes. Both basically point to the fact that the string being passed needs to escape the curly braces (somehow).

Error (single quote):

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal [Break On This Error]
>
> init('{

Comment: What is the *exact* JSON string the browser is seeing?

Comment: Even with that example above (created during the same process), it gives me the exact same error.

Comment: What is the browser getting?! Show us, that helps a lot, you know.

Comment: I added the exact error from Firebug at the bottom. Is that not enough? Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Does it work if you replace the escaped double quotes `\"` with simple quotes `'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is not in the JSON string, it's in the other bit of code.

`pw.println("<body onload=\"init('"+jsonString+"');\">");` is really crude attempt to add an onload event.

Don't try to add the JSON string into the HTML string, it wont work because of the quotes, unless you *doubly* escape the JSON string, which is just silly.

Currently you output will look like:

```
<body onload="init('{"id":1, ... }');">
                     ^--- syntax error after this
```

It will try to execute the JS code `init('{`.

Comment: Certainly obvious enough, but if the actual markup the browser was borking on was included, it would have been very clear where the exact problem was.

Comment: Also note the Chrome Console literally tells you exactly where the error occurs (see the Console tab and click on the link to the far right of the error text). Consider abandoning `alert()`-based debugging, and switch to the much saner and more useful `console` debugging.

Comment: Jared - Again, this was the exact json string I used. Frits - Thanks for the answer. I'll look into alternatives.

Comment: @g1021maxED - Why would it have been so hard to include the actual markup causing the problem? We're trying to help you, y'know.

Comment: I know - The actual string is a total of about 220 nodes. A string far too long to dissect. So I tested with a simplified example (I attached). It gave me the same results. I figured it would be easier to determine failure on a simpler example..

Comment: @g1021maxED - Oops, forgot to give you the test fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/eQRBk/

Answer (score 2):

Frits was able to figure out your problem, which was good. I would *definitely* take his advice and move away *quickly* from using `body onload`.

For instance:

```
(function run(){
    var data = '{"id":1,"name":"Joe Smith","data":{"email":"smith@gmail.com","phone":"555-123-4567","title":"CFO","instanceControllerTagLibraryApi":{"developmentMode":false}},"children":[],"instanceControllerTagLibraryApi":{"developmentMode":false}}';

    function init(){
        console.log(data, JSON.parse(data));
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', init);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('load', init);
    }
​})();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/eQRBk/1/

Notice the use of `window.addEventListener` (and the legacy `window.attachEvent` for older IE versions). And that `console.log` works better in Chrome and Firebug; IE's console is a little more frustrating in how it logs objects, in my opinion.

Using what you've given, you could (and I would suggest should) handle it differently. Forgive me, however, I'm not that well-versed in Java and JSP is all I know (barely). So...?

```
<%

String jsonString = "'{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Joe Smith\",\"data\":{\"email\":\"smith@gmail.com\",\"phone\":\"555-123-4567\",\"title\":\"CFO\",\"instanceControllerTagLibraryApi\":{\"developmentMode\":false}},\"children\":[],\"instanceControllerTagLibraryApi\":{\"developmentMode\":false}}'";

%>
<script>
(function run(){
    var data = <%=jsonString%>;

    function init(){
        console.log(data, JSON.parse(data));
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', init);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('load', init);
    }
​})();​
</script>
```

And then you can insert that JSP page into the `head` or the `body` and it will work fine. I also imagine you could set it up to dynamically inject that data into the JSP page. But, like I said, I'm kinda waving my hands here.